# How to auto populate the foreign identity key column in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, auto-populate

This has been bugging me for over a week or two.  Honestly, it is pretty simple, but somehow I just can't wrap my head properly around the problem.

I have two tables:

user

---

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| user_id | username | password |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

message

---

```
+------------+----+---------+
| message_id | id | message |
+------------+----+---------+

//id(fk)references user_id
```

When I insert the information explicitly like this...

```sql
INSERT INTO message (id, username) VALUES ( '13', 'a;al;dld;ldladda');
```

...it gets inserted into the `message` table, but somehow when I do this (which is what I want)...

```sql
INSERT INTO message(id, username) VALUES (
    (SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE username = '$this->username'), '$this->username'
);
```

...nothing is being inserted. I have searched the depths of Google to find the answer, but I am confused with all these procedures which I have tried but are not working.  I am a newbie to MySQL, and I am using phpMyAdmin.

I want the primary  key `id` to be automatically inserted into the table while I am inserting the `message`.  so that I can know which `message` belongs to which `user`.

Comment: maybe add the table creates of the 2 tables to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

okay, i understand now. so i have just founded out that i can use the lastInsertId to get the last inserted id  from the user table which i can use to get the autoincremented id. so half of the problem is already solved here is the code.

$insert_into_database = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO login(username,password) VALUES('$this->username','$this->password')");

$insert_into_database->execute();

$id =  $db->lastInsertId();

so i got that now, so basically half of the problem is solved, what i want to do now is to insert that $id into the child table, which is going to connect each user to a message in a many to many relationship. the child table is on another page and when i do this it's not working.

$insert_info_into = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO info( id, message)       VALUES('$id', '$this->message')");

$insert_info_into->execute();

i am getting this error.
Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\practice\config.php on line 44

so how can i do this can i have a trigger or something which i don't really know how to do.